# why does my images keep overwriting itself instead of showing each image in the for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, spring-boot

I've been trying to get my images to appropriately show in their respective table cell, however it appears my images are just overwriting each other in the first cell instead of printing it in the next cell.

I been looking at this for a day or two now, perhaps a fresh set of eyes will spot the problem.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <c:forEach var="tempMuscleGroup" items="${musclegroups}">
        <tr>
            <td class="not_mapped_style" style="text-align: center">
                <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/musclegroup/list/${tempMuscleGroup.name}/">${tempMuscleGroup.name} </a><br> ${tempMuscleGroup.description}<br>
                <img id="imageId" src="" />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            console.log("${tempMuscleGroup.name}");

            if ("${tempMuscleGroup.name}" == "Abdominals") {
                document.getElementById("imageId").src = "/static/images/abs.jpg";
            }
            if ("${tempMuscleGroup.name}" == "Biceps") {
                document.getElementById("imageId").src = "/static/images/bicep.jpg";
            }
            if ("${tempMuscleGroup.name}" == "Calves") {
                document.getElementById("imageId").src = "/static/images/calves.jpg";

            }
            if ("${tempMuscleGroup.name}" == "Chest") {
                document.getElementById("imageId").src = "/static/images/chest.jpg";

            }
            if ("${tempMuscleGroup.name}" == "Forearms") {
                document.getElementById("imageId").src = "/static/images/forearms.jpg";
            }
            if ("${tempMuscleGroup.name}" == "Quads") {
                document.getElementById("imageId").src = "/static/images/quads.jpg";

            }
            if ("${tempMuscleGroup.name}" == "Shoulders") {
                document.getElementById("imageId").src = "/static/images/shoulder.jpg";
            }
            if ("${tempMuscleGroup.name}" == "Traps") {
                document.getElementById("imageId").src = "/static/images/traps.jpg";

            }
        </script>

    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Comment: The id of the image is static, it's "imageId" for every image, hence `gEBI` finds only the first element.

Comment: I did try also creating a <img > tag for each tempMuscleGroup i loop over, however it still only prints all the images in the first iteration of the loop, albeit it does not overwrite one image thus leaving 8 images under the first muscle group i loop

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you try to render multiple items with the same ID - `imageId`. Each one of the for loops creates a script that calls the element with the ID `imageId` and set's its ID over and over again, because in HTML *IDs are unique*. You might want to set a class instead.

But there's another problem, which isn't an error but is definitely a problem:

In your backend, you have this for loop:

```
<c:forEach var="tempMuscleGroup" items="${musclegroups}">
```

That renders the code in it `n` times (for `n` musclegroups). Then, in each time it renders, you place a script which has a lot of ifs for a simple check. **Bad practice!** Why? Because you render an image through your backend and then ask frontend to determine which picture it is, adding bloat of code. The code rendered will look like:

```
if ("Biceps" == "Abdominals") {
    document.getElementById("imageId").src = "/static/images/abs.jpg";
}
if ("Biceps" == "Biceps") {
    document.getElementById("imageId").src = "/static/images/bicep.jpg";
}
if ("Biceps" == "Calves") {
    document.getElementById("imageId").src = "/static/images/calves.jpg";

}
if ("Biceps" == "Chest") {
    document.getElementById("imageId").src = "/static/images/chest.jpg";

}
if ("Biceps" == "Forearms") {
    document.getElementById("imageId").src = "/static/images/forearms.jpg";
}
if ("Biceps" == "Quads") {
    document.getElementById("imageId").src = "/static/images/quads.jpg";

}
if ("Biceps" == "Shoulders") {
    document.getElementById("imageId").src = "/static/images/shoulder.jpg";
}
if ("Biceps" == "Traps") {
    document.getElementById("imageId").src = "/static/images/traps.jpg";
}
```

You'd never write this code yourself, wouldn't you? Of course not. And this huge chunk of code gets repeated for each one of your muscles. *So what?*

Firstly, you added an extra 6.704kb of code for this simple action, and that's just for repeating this code 8 times. It doesn't sound a lot, but you're adding `~n^2*105` bytes where `n` is the number of items, where it isn't necessary.

Plus, perhaps more importantly, it makes the code rendered ugly and hard to read when debugging.

Instead, do this in the backend - use your JSP code to decide what the `src` should be in any way you'd like - having a preset constant `HashMap` of muscles & image sources, saving the image sources in the database and pulling them when needed, using an if statement like this (which is less recommended as it is still bloated). You just saved a lot of clutter for yourself & bandwidth for users :)

In this way, this solves your bug (which should still be fixed as identical IDs are invalid HTML) as you don't need to dynamically get the image, so all you'd need to do is remove the `id` tag from your `img` tag. You don't really need a way to dynamically reference it now as this is done from backend. If you do, I'd recommend either setting a class or a *unique* id (perhaps generate one from the muscle name, like `img-{musclenamehere}`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions it helped me find a solution! I will post the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to be working for what i need, thanks for all the kind suggestions!

```
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <c:forEach var="tempMuscleGroup" items="${musclegroups}">
        <tr>
            <td class="not_mapped_style" style="text-align: center"><a
                href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/musclegroup/list/${tempMuscleGroup.name}/">
                    ${tempMuscleGroup.name} </a><br> ${tempMuscleGroup.description}<br>

                <img id="imageId" class="image" src="" /></td>
        </tr>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            console.log("${tempMuscleGroup.name}");

            if ("${tempMuscleGroup.name}" == "Abdominals") {
                document.getElementsByClassName("image")[0].src = "/static/images/abs.jpg";

            } else if ("${tempMuscleGroup.name}" == "Biceps") {
                document.getElementsByClassName("image")[1].src = "/static/images/bicep.jpg";
                console.log("INSIDE BICSEPS" + "${tempMuscleGroup.name}");
            } else if ("${tempMuscleGroup.name}" == "Calves") {
                document.getElementsByClassName("image")[2].src = "/static/images/calves.jpg";

            } else if ("${tempMuscleGroup.name}" == "Chest") {
                document.getElementsByClassName("image")[3].src = "/static/images/chest.jpg";

            } else if ("${tempMuscleGroup.name}" == "Forearms") {
                document.getElementsByClassName("image")[4].src = "/static/images/forearms.jpg";
            } else if ("${tempMuscleGroup.name}" == "Quads") {
                document.getElementsByClassName("image")[5].src = "/static/images/quads.jpg";

            } else if ("${tempMuscleGroup.name}" == "Shoulders") {
                document.getElementsByClassName("image")[6].src = "/static/images/shoulder.jpg";
            } else if ("${tempMuscleGroup.name}" == "Traps") {
                document.getElementsByClassName("image")[7].src = "/static/images/traps.jpg";
            }
        </script>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```